# How do I set the fontsize fo the yaxis labels for radar graph in chartjs

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I want to increase the font size of Yaxis step numbers.

I am using the below code

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                            type: 'radar',
                            data: data,
                            options: {
                                responsive: true,
                                elements: {
                                        line: {
                                            borderWidth: 3
                                        }
                                    },
                                
                                plugins: {
                                    legend: {
                                        display: false,
                                    }
                                },
                                scales: {
                                            r: {
                                                max: 50,
                                                min: 0,
                                                ticks: {
                                                    stepSize: 5,
                                                    textStrokeColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                                                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                                                    //backdropColor: 'rgb(47, 56, 62)'
                                                    //fontSize: 200
                                                    
                                                },
                                                angleLines: {
                                                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0,0.65)',
                                                },

                                                grid: {
                                                    color: "darkgray",
                                                },
                                                
                                            },
                                            
                                        
                                        },      
                            },
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the steps on how to set the font size for the y-axis labels (step numbers) in a radar graph using Chart.js:**

1. Access the ticks configuration:

Within the scales configuration of your chart, you'll find the r scale, which represents the radial axis in a radar chart. Within the r scale, locate the ticks configuration, which allows you to customize the appearance of tick marks and labels.

2. Set the fontSize property:

Inside the ticks configuration, add the fontSize property and set it to the desired font size in pixels. Here's the updated code snippet:

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'radar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    // ... other options
    scales: {
      r: {
        // ... other scale options
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 5,
          // ... other tick options
          fontSize: 20 // Set the font size here
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```